# Strange definition method (def) in Groovy. Looks like an object or function with no name

Tags: groovy, collections, declaration

I came across this in code a few times, and cannot figure out what this declaration is exactly. It appears to simply be a collection of variables, but is being passed together as though it is some singular variable or object itself holding all 3 values. 
What exactly is this?

```
def foo(filename) {
    // Below you can find an assignment I don't understand:
    def (id, company, type) = roo(filename)
    AClass.findByStuff(id, company, type)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Groovy's [multiple assignment feature](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_multiple_assignment). In short words - it expects a collection of elements on the right side and a list of variables in brackets to assign elements from the list to on the left side. For instance:

```groovy
def (a, b, c) = [1, 10, 100, 1000]

assert a == 1
assert b == 10
assert c == 100
```

This assignment prevents from throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and if the number of variables on the left side is greater than the number of elements in collection on the right side, then it simply assigns `null` value, for instance:

```
def (a, b, c) = [1, 10]

assert a == 1
assert b == 10
assert c == null
```

Comment: Thanks! Question though. Why did the assignment skip the value 10(second index) when assigning?
Also once this declaration is made, it can namelessly be passed around as though it is a variable correct? similar to the way it was in my OP code?

Comment: That was a typo. It assigns values in order. And yes - after assignment these variables can be used as a regular variables. This is just a shorthand version of assigning multiple variables based on values taken from a collection.